# Why shouldn't dark area analysis be used to estimate carbon content on high carbon hypoeutectoid steels?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, steel

I had this thought with me for quite some time, that you can't use the usual formula for estimating carbon content on a Nital etched hypoeutectoid sample (DarkArea*0.77) if the steel obviously has more than around 0.6% carbon.

I am pretty sure I read that somewhere, but I can't find that, and I might have been operating in a false premise for some time now.

Comment: How ist it obvious that the steel has more than 0.6% carbon?
As a hypoeutectoid steel, it could lie between 0.6% and around 0.8%, right?

Comment: A steel with more than 0.6% carbon will have a very dark structure under nital etching after being annealed, because of the pearlite. If you're certainly dealing with a hypoeutectoid steel, and it looks very dark under the microscope, it is usually a very good bet you're dealing with more than 0.6%C. And yes, that is the issue you have to deal with, not knowing where in the 0.6%-0.8% scale it is, as I believe the usual formula won't give you the precise carbon content. But I'm not sure why I believe that, even though I think I read it somewhere. I wanted someone to maybe point me to a source.